# How to fix an error which occurs when I am trying to delete an object related to another objects in Django app as an admin?

Tags: python, django

I have a class named Customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    # One to one relationship: customer is a user
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # Returns the string representation of an object
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

... And a class named Order (customer can have many orders).

```
class Order(models.Model):
    objects = None
    # many to one relationship: customer can have many orders
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_order = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    # You can access the parent class from inside a method of a child class by using super()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

When I am trying to remove the object of class Customer I have created, named Kasia (which is probably superuser as well) I cannot do it. I have previously deleted this customer's orders and now they are set to Null value. There is a type error and a message: 'Model instances without primary key values are unhashable'. The exception location is as follows:
C:\Users\kasia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 536, in **hash**

When I want to delete user, the same thing happens. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that happens because you set `id = None` try to delete this function and see what will happen

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.id = None
```

Comment: Your answer worked, why deleting this function was the correct solution?

Comment: The problem did not from function, It's from `self.id = None` every model should have a unique id and you set it with `Non`  if u delete this line everything will work fine.